# why use letters as function name and parameters in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function (a) {
    var r = a.fn.domManip,
        d = "_tmplitem",
        q = /^[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|\{\{\! /,
        b = {}, f = {}, e, p = {
            key: 0,
            data: {}
        }, h = 0,
        c = 0,
        l = [];

    function g(e, d, g, i) {
        var c = {
            data: i || (d ? d.data : {}),
            _wrap: d ? d._wrap : null,
            tmpl: null,
            parent: d || null,
            nodes: [],
            calls: u,
            nest: w,
            wrap: x,
            html: v,
            update: t
        };
        e && a.extend(c, e, {
            nodes: [],
            parent: d
        });
        if (g) {
            c.tmpl = g;
            c._ctnt = c._ctnt || c.tmpl(a, c);
            c.key = ++h;
            (l.length ? f : b)[h] = c
        }
        return c
    }
    a.each({
        appendTo: "append",
        prependTo: "prepend",
        insertBefore: "before",
        insertAfter: "after",
        replaceAll: "replaceWith"...
```

Question:

Above code is taken from http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js.

There are many letters(a,b,c...) used here. And I have seen other js files also use this way. So i just wonder what is the reason behind this? use letters as function name, parameters and variables to save memory or for what?

Comment: It's called minification. That's why they called it `min.js`

Comment: Because what you see is the *min* version. Read this one http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a minified version of the code. Which means function names and parameters are shortened in string length to preserve file size.

The same happens with the popular jQuery library. For example, compare the two versions, the [minified](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js) and [unminified](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js) versions.

Comment: good to know it. so if i saw a minified version, which tool i can use to restore it back to the original version?

Comment: I often use this tool > http://jscompress.com/, in combination with gzip compression on the server.

Comment: is there a way to uncompress?

Comment: Not in an automated manner. You could infer what the functions and parameters are for, and then replace all instances of their names with a best-guess identifier. But then, what's the point? Most libraries release both a minified and unminified version, and trying to uncompress a large library such as jQuery would require many man-hours.

Answer (score 1):

It's called minification, it's used both to obfuscate (to some extent) and to reduce the overall size of the JavaScript code.

Tools like YUICompressor will do this for you. I have it set up as a post build task that runs through all my JavaScript before I deploy.

Answer (score 1):

That's a minified js file, (hence ".min." in the filename). Variable names are cut down to save bandwidth usage. Think about people with bandwidth caps, or transferring over slow networks, every little can help.

Answer (score 0):

You extracted this from jquery.tmpl.**min**.js. Javascript files are oftem minimized by a tool in order do reduce network bandwidth and load faster.

During development, normal variable names are used to increase readability.

Answer (score 0):

Because it has been [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29). Full variable names are not needed for the code to run so developers usually run code through a tool to remove redundant material to keep the size down and improve download times.

You can download the full source code of jQuery and work with that, replacing it with the minified version when you deploy the website.